# How to get the final redirected URL which has some JavaScript's?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, urllib2

I used urllib2 to get the final redirected url of a web-link. For eg: http://tbk.bz/t72qx4v3
I am getting link as:

```
http://taskbucks.com/artcl_out?artcl=24713df2ffb748ec8464638df61d2298
```

But, browsers gave the redirected final URL like this:

```
www.holidayiq.com/blog/6-high-octane-adventure-sports-in-india-that-will-get-your-heart-in-your-throat-1831.html/
```

I wish to get this final URL in python.

Comment: post your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on the http://taskbucks.com/artcl_out?artcl=24713df2ffb748ec8464638df61d2298 page, there is a "document ready" event listener that makes a browser submit a form on load which would eventually redirect you to the final page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fsid").val(new Fingerprint().get());
        $("#fsidpe").val(new Fingerprint({canvas: true}).get());
        submitReport();
    });
    function submitReport() {
        $("#articleCheck").submit();
    }
</script>
```

`urllib2` is not a browser and would not submit a form on page load.

Instead, I would use tools like [`Mechanize`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) in order to submit this form:

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> 
>>> br = mechanize.Browser()
>>> br.open("http://tbk.bz/t72qx4v3")
>>> br.select_form("articleCheck")
>>> br.submit()
>>> br.geturl()
'http://www.holidayiq.com/blog/6-high-octane-adventure-sports-in-india-that-will-get-your-heart-in-your-throat-1831.html?utm_source=taskbucks&utm_medium=share&utm_campaign=referral&channel=taskbucks'
```

Comment: I am trying to add unique user-agent to it by adding.   br.addheaders=[('User-agent','Android')]